# Geometry has too many edges error on GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I was trying to perform an intersection geometry operation on an asset I uploaded which I converted to a feature collection and I keep getting the `"intersection: Layer error: Collection.geometry: Geometry has too many edges (18183861 > 2000000)."` error regardless of size of polygon.

Link to my work
https://code.earthengine.google.com/73f647cc64d430d60b69a021127c148f

```
// converting the asset to feature collection

var irrigation = ee.FeatureCollection(Irrigation);

// Simplify each feature in the collection, by mapping the
// .simplify() function over it. 
//var simplifiedirrigation = irrigation.map(function(irrigation) {
//  return irrigation.simplify({maxError: 100});
//});

// create a polygon

var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
  [[5.364373355349645,7.161499312988462], [5.364373355349645,7.161499312988462], [5.891717105349645,7.597311534607618], [5.891717105349645,7.597311534607618], [5.364373355349645,7.161499312988462]]
]);

// Compute the intersection.

var intersection = polygon.intersection(Irrigation);

// displaying data

Map.addLayer(irrigation, {}, 'Irrigation Potential');
Map.addLayer(intersection, {}, 'intersection');
Map.setCenter(5.7621,7.1942, 8);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var intersection = polygon.intersection(Irrigation);
```

You should avoid performing geometry operations directly on large feature collections, because that converts the entire collection into a single geometry object, which is hard for Earth Engine to process efficiently.

Instead, perform the intersection for each feature individually:

```js
var intersection = Irrigation
    .filterBounds(polygon)  // Discard ones that don't intersect at all
    .map(function (feature) {
        return feature.intersection(polygon);  // Compute the intersection of each
    });

Map.addLayer(intersection);
```

The result of this will be a feature collection.

Note: Because you did not share your feature collection, I could not test this with your data. However, I did notice that your `polygon` has only 2 distinct points and collapses into a line, which may not be what you want. You can check the polygon by writing `Map.addLayer(polygon);` to view it.